# Loop through poco-class properties

Tags: c#

```
public partial class Foo
{
    public struct ContainerOne
    {
        public const long Sub1 = 1;
        public const long Sub2 = 2;
    }

    public struct ContainerTwo
    {
        public const long Sub3 = 3;
        public const long Sub4 = 4;
    }

}
```

Is there any way to make a nested foreach that gets each container name, with an inne loop that gets each property name + value?

Hope you get the idea, otherwise ill elaborate, thanks!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, like this:

```
var fooType = typeof(Foo);
foreach(var type in fooType.GetNestedTypes())
{
    Console.WriteLine(type.Name);
    foreach(var field in type.GetFields())
    {
        Console.WriteLine("{0} = {1}",field.Name,field.GetValue(null));
    }
}
```

Live example: http://rextester.com/PNV12550

Comment: Great, looks like what i need. 2 quicks questions: 1. How do i filter the first loop to only look for struct properties? 2. `type.GetFields()` needs an argument, what should i pass? Thanks

Comment: Ignore the second questions, i accidently used `GetField` instead of `GetFields()` :)

Comment: You can change the outer loop to `fooType.GetNestedTypes().Where(t => t.IsValueType)` to look for just structs.